# How can I write a SQL query left joining 2 tables that lists all entries on the left table, but only once?

Tags: sql, left-join

My question is a little complicated so I'm not sure I summed it up so well in the title, but it's like this--

I have two tables: a BOOKDETAIL table with data on a lot of books, and a STOCKDIARY table with the sales history on books we've ordered before. Not every book in the BOOKDETAIL table has a record in the STOCKDIARY. I want to list every book in the BOOKDETAIL table, and sort it first by those that have sold recently, and then alphabetically for everything else. This is as far as I've gotten it to work:

```
SELECT BOOKDETAIL.*, STOCKDIARY.DATENEW, STOCKDIARY.PRODUCT
FROM BOOKDETAIL
LEFT JOIN STOCKDIARY
ON BOOKDETAIL.ISBN = STOCKDIARY.PRODUCT
ORDER BY STOCKDIARY.DATENEW DESC, bookdetail.Title ASC
```

This does list every book, but if the book has sold multiple times, that book will appear as many times on the list. I want each book to appear only once!

I tried adding this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE STOCKDIARY.DATENEW IN (
SELECT MAX(DATENEW) AS DATENEW
FROM STOCKDIARY
GROUP BY PRODUCT)
```

But then I only see books that have an entry in the STOCKDIARY. How can I get this to work so that every book shows up but only once?

Comment: Please post sample data and the desired result.  Also please fix your tags to indicate whether your question is for MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will bring back only the latest record for each book on `stockdiary`. Because it is in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause it will also show records existing on `bookdetail` but not on `stockdiary`.

The case statement in the order by puts books not bought at all at the bottom rather than the top. Mysql doesn't have `nulls last`.

```
select b.*, s.last_sold, s.product
  from bookdetail b
  left join (select product, max(datenew) as last_sold
               from stockdiary
              group by product) s
    on b.isbn = s.product
 order by case when s.last_sold is null
               then '1900-01-01' else s.last_sold end desc,
          b.title
```

Comment: I tried this one and the query wouldn't return any results, but when I tried this for the join it worked:   left join (select product, datenew
               from stockdiary
              group by product) s

Comment: As an FYI, because you have something in the select list (`datenew`) without an aggregate function applied to it, and you are grouping by product, an arbitrary `datenew` value for each product will be shown, rather than the LAST date in which product was sold (which is what you said you wanted). In other words, you're picking up dates of sales that are not necessarily the last. In any database other than MySQL, this would actually throw a syntax error. Just because you are returning results doesn't mean those are the results you want.

Comment: If you want to know why the above is not returning results, post sample data.

Comment: Ahh, Ok, that's important. 
I figured out it wasn't returning results because I forgot to add s.last_sold to select up at the top. Now it works they way you suggested, except I left out the "case when" part because it's sorting everything without order history to the bottom already. I think they're not actually NULL fields: there aren't any rows for them in the STOCKDIARY.

Answer (score 0):

change your second query (where clause) as:

```
WHERE STOCKDIARY.DATENEW = (
SELECT MAX(s.DATENEW)
FROM STOCKDIARY s 
Where s.PRODUCT=BOOKDETAIL.ISBN)
```